# CPU Cache/Memory Access Time Anomalies

Tags: java, c++, memory, memory-management, cpu-cache

We are trying to optimize heavy memory operations in Java and ran into some anomalies. From our data, we concluded the hypothesis, that an array/memory block might be loaded into CPU cache caused by a lot of accesses, but after cloning this array multiple times, the cache becomes full and moves the initial array back into RAM.

To test this, we set up a benchmark. It does the following:

1. Create an array with a given size
2. Write some data into the fields
3. Read/iterate it a million times (to push it into CPU cache)
4. Clone it once into a new array
5. Clone the new array into a new array and use the new one for the next time a given amount of times

Additionally, after each of these steps the array is iterated three times and the needed time is measured for each iteration. Here is the code:

```
private static long[] read(byte[] array, int count, boolean logTimes) {
    long[] times = null;
    if (logTimes) {
        times = new long[count];
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
        if (logTimes) {
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            times[n] = time;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return times;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int clones = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    byte[] array = new byte[arraySize];
    long[] initialReadTimes = read(array, 3, true);
    // Fill with some non-zero content
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (byte) i;
    }
    long[] afterWriteTimes = read(array, 3, true);

    // Make this array important, so it lands in CPU Cache
    read(array, 1_000_000, false);
    long[] afterReadTimes = read(array, 3, true);

    long[] afterFirstCloneReadTimes = null;
    byte[] copy = new byte[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, copy, 0, array.length);
    for (int i = 1; i <= clones; i++) {
        byte[] copy2 = new byte[copy.length];
        System.arraycopy(copy, 0, copy2, 0, copy.length);
        copy = copy2;
        if (i == 1) {
            afterFirstCloneReadTimes = read(array, 3, true);
        }
    }

    long[] afterAllClonesReadTimes = read(array, 3, true);

    // Write to CSV
    ...
    System.out.println("Finished.");
}
```

We ran this benchmark with arraysize=10,000 and clones=10,000,000 on a 2nd gen i5 with 16 GB RAM:
[image]

There was quite a lot of variation though, the 2nd and 3rd runs had different times sometimes or there were peaks in the 2nd and 3rd run of the last reading benchmark.

These results seem pretty confusing. I think that this could show that upon array initialization, it is not immediately loaded into CPU cache, because the initial read times are relatively high. After writing nothing seems to have changed. Only after iterating a lot the access times become faster, while the first run is always slower (because of the measuring overhead that runs between the readings?). Also cloning/filling memory with new arrays does not seem to have an impact at all. Could anyone explain these results?

We assumed that some of this might stem from java specific memory management, so we tried to reimplement the benchmark in C++:

```
void read(unsigned char array[], int length, int count, std::vector<long int> & logTimes) {
    for (int c = 0; c < count; c++) {
        int sum = 0;
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1;
        if (count <= 3) {
            t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
        if (count <= 3) {
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            long int duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
            std::cout << duration << " ns\n";
            logTimes.push_back(duration);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** args)
{
    int ARRAYSIZE = 10000;
    int CLONES = 10000000;
    std::vector<long int> initialTimes, afterWritingTimes, afterReadTimes, afterFirstCloneTimes, afterCloneTimes, null;
    unsigned char array[ARRAYSIZE];
    read(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3, initialTimes);
    for (long long i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    std::cout << "Reads after writing:\n";
    read(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3, afterWritingTimes);

    read(array, ARRAYSIZE, 1000000, null);
    std::cout << "Reads after 1M Reads:\n";
    read(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3, afterReadTimes);

    unsigned char copy[ARRAYSIZE];
    unsigned char * ptr_copy = copy;
    std::memcpy(ptr_copy, array, ARRAYSIZE);
    for (long long i = 0; i < CLONES; i++) {
        unsigned char copy2[ARRAYSIZE];
        std::memcpy(copy2, ptr_copy, ARRAYSIZE);
        ptr_copy = copy2;
        if (i == 0) {
            read(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3, afterFirstCloneTimes);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Reads after cloning:\n";
    read(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3, afterCloneTimes);

    writeTimesToCSV(initialTimes, afterWritingTimes, afterReadTimes, afterFirstCloneTimes, afterCloneTimes);
    std::cout << "Finished.\n";
}
```

Using the same parameters, we got the following results:

[image]

So in C++ the times are rather similar to each other, with some strange peaks in the 2nd run. This seems to show that above faster timings were caused by java optimizations (or rather suboptimal handling in the first readings). Does this mean that the CPU cache is not involved at all?

Comment: Micro benchmarking in Java is complicated, you should use jmh. For example you need to warm up the JIT and give it time to compile the `read` method before measuring. Also I'm not sure if nanotime is precise enough for a 10K loop of reading an array (depends on java version, cpu, os). It's also possible that the JIT compiler realises that your clone loop only needs to be executed once because the next iterations have no side effects.

Comment: There is a micro benchmark framework [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) that helps you with benchmarking in Java. What your code is missing is a warmup phase for example. A warmup tries to ensure that your code is already optimized when you measure. Otherwise optimization might kick in in the middle of your test ([JVM Options](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)). Also, do you evaluate your garbage collection log to make sure you do not count GC times?

Comment: @assylias @ cmoetzing Thanks for your suggestions. I had a look at jmh but couldn't find how to implement above benchmark equivalently, because jmh seems to build on independent atomic benchmark functions. We need to run that big method "once" and in order and not measure its whole computation time, but the times of highly context-sensitive intermediate steps. It does allow per-benchmark setups and teardowns, so the only possibility I see is to clone the code 5 times and benchmark-annotate a different read()-call each time. Or did you think of a different solution?

Comment: So I tried to implement it as described, starting with a setup method that allocates an array and iterates once over it in the benchmark method. There are two issues: 1) Using Level.Invocation to let setup be executed before each read is [strongly discouraged](http://javadox.com/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-core/1.7/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Level.html#Invocation), because the iterations take a lot less than 1ms. 2) Only the first read iteration after each event can be measured.